# How to parse array of JSON in Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, dictionary, swift3

I am getting some data from Socket which I would like to access but I am getting error saying can't convert NSArray to NSDictionary each time.

```
struct SocketEventHandler {
    let event: String
    let id: UUID
    let callback: NormalCallback

    func executeCallback(with items: [Any], withAck ack: Int, withSocket socket: SocketIOClient) {
        callback(items, SocketAckEmitter(socket: socket, ackNum: ack))
    }
}


let onFriendRequestStatus: NormalCallback = {dataArray,socketAck in
        AppLog.debug(tag: TAG, msg: "Response: \(dataArray)")
        AppLog.debug(tag: TAG, msg: "Response: \(dataArray[0])")
        let response  = dataArray[0] as! Dictionary<String, Any> **// APP CRASHES ON THIS LINE**
}
```

**Response :-**

```
[
    {
        "status": "A",
        "acceptorId": 126,
        "id": 94,
        "createdAt": "2017-06-05T09:50:42.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2017-06-05T09:52:26.000Z",
        "userId": 126,
        "friendId": 401
    }
]
```

Error - Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x102f0de00) to 'NSDictionary' (0x102f0e2d8).

Answer (score 2):

May be you are having 2d array means the elements of `dataArray` are also `Array` not `Dictionary`.

```
if let response = dataArray[0] as? [[String: Any]], let dictionary = response.first {

    print(dictionary["status"])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a breakpoint on sentence crashes, and then use following command to check what exactly the `dataArray` is:

```
po print(dataArray)
```